# How to give conditions for calling max () aliases from field selected from a table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I had Mysql code like here :

```
SELECT SERVICE_NUMBER , count( * ) ,  max(STATUS) as FIRST_STATUS
FROM RPT_LOG
WHERE FIRST_STATUS='S'          
GROUP BY SERVICE_NUMBER
HAVING count( * ) > 2;
```

Anyone can help me to give conditions from alias like *FIRST_STATUS = ' S '*.
because i had an error : Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the value of the alias `FIRST_STATUS` in the `WHERE` clause, but its value depends on the `GROUP BY`. You can only use that alias in the `HAVING` clause.

```
HAVING STATUS = 'S'
```

Comment: but I want to give more than one Having conditions , the first is having count ( * ) and the second is max ( STATUS ) = ' S'. So what should I use to combine both of these conditions ?

Comment: Use `AND`: `HAVING count(*) > 2 AND FIRST_STATUS='S'`